# Three.js WebGLRenderer With Existing Context

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js, webgl, webxr

I have a `WebGLRenderingContext` ([XR-compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/makeXRCompatible)) that is being drawn on by regular WebGL calls, and I also want to render on it using a Three.js `WebGLRender`. For some reason, creating a `THREE.WebGLRenderer` using the existing context (even if `render` is never called) makes the canvas go blank, and no drawing shows up after that.

Answer (score -1):

If you check [HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-canvas-getcontext) you’ll see you cannot share the context for 2D and webgl.
A workaround could be to get a new context from a hidden canvas, that’s what some websites do.

Comment: Uh, but @programmer didn't say they were using the canvas for 2D, but that it would be used for WebGL by both THREE.js and directly?

Comment: AFAIK just instancing that requires to define if it’s 2D or webgl cannot be used for other purpose

Comment: The canvas is only used for WebGL, and the `WebGLRenderer` is created using an existing context, so there should only be one context from the canvas.

Comment: If you add some code it’ll be clearer I think

Comment: Are you setting `renderer.autoClear = false;`??